# React JS Custom Charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been exploring available chart libraries to use with react js though none seem to match my criteria.

I need to be able to set gradients within the chart, set "average" points hence the small dots within the doughnut.

The text I figured I can overlay to create the desired affect.

Chart.js I could get close however, there was not enough documentation to provide examples on how to execute gradients within the doughnut.

With going down a Canvas custom route as a complete last resort, are there any libraries that could provide what I'm looking for based on my design?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the old jquery knobs which is been ported nicely to react, you can create two knobs one inside the other to represent the average inside, etc. You'll figure it out. It is not the same as your picture, but it would look nice.

The other way is to hardcode this library to make what you are attempting to.

[React-canvas-knob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas-knob)

[Old jquery knob examples](http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/)

Answer (score 1):

You can us an image with the gradient printed on it. Than add the blue circle in the middle. Or make it entirely one image. Everything dynamic like the number and optionally an animated arrow you can do on top of it. It saves loading time and coding effort.

Comment: The doughnut needs to animate on load and will update with live data an image may not help but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

My top choice would be the [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) library. As stated on the introduction on the [documentation](https://d3js.org/#introduction),

> D3 allows you to bind arbitrary data to a Document Object Model (DOM),
>   and then apply data-driven transformations to the document. For
>   example, you can use D3 to generate an HTML table from an array of
>   numbers. Or, use the same data to create an interactive SVG bar chart
>   with smooth transitions and interaction.

You may refer to the vast library of examples over [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) and [here](https://observablehq.com/explore).